# meta analysis of combination therapy in single arm studies

Tags: meta-analysis

I want to do meta analysis of proportion (Outcome).

My study has different type of treatments, for example, single arm studies with one or more than one drug combination treatment.

Do I need to do correlation among arms before doing a meta analysis?

Do I need to do a meta regression considering all arms as individual study?

Do I need to classify all single drug, double drug or more and do separate Meta analysis?

Comment: single arm ? all arms? state objective of your study and the data and design?

Comment: I would recommend simply meta-regression

Comment: Or possibly network meta-analysis but from the sparse details you give it is impossible to say.

Comment: To be more clear, I am doing Systematic review and want to do meta anlysis of existing historical data to know what is the Objective response rate of all treatments available for aprticular type of disease.My studies selected have different type of treatments. some are single arm,some are double arm , some are arms with single drud and some are single arm with multiple arms. I am interested in the meta analysis pf proportion of events in all arms of studies selected. Only treatment arms not placebo. My outcome variable is only proportion ( Objective response rate)

Comment: o be more clear, I am doing Systematic review and want to do meta anlysis of existing historical data to know what is the Objective response rate of all treatments available for a particular type of disease.My studies selected have different type of treatments. some are single arm,some are double arm , some are arms with single drud and some are single arm with multiple arms. I am interested in the meta analysis pf proportion of events in all arms of studies selected. Only treatment arms not placebo. My outcome variable is only proportion ( Objective response rate).